# Better to put simple route code in controllers to keep continuity?

Tags: php, laravel

This is a fairly simple question about PHP and the Laravel framework (although this could be applied to similar frameworks like flask). Is it generally considered to be better programming practice to put even a few lines of code into controllers in order to maintain the practice of as little code as possible in routes with the code being in controllers.

For example--should this auth code be moved into a controller, or is it fine here?

```
Route::get('/show-login-status', function() {
    # You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user) {
        echo 'You are logged in.';
        dump($user->toArray());
    } else {
        echo 'You are not logged in.';
    }
    return;
});
```

Comment: This is really an opinion based question. There are as many "best practices" as there are developers, if you ask me. My opinion is that you shouldn't have any code in the route definition. It makes it absolutely non reusable. (Actually, an anonymous function in the route is more or less a "one off"-controller). You should point it to a proper controller class, and then use middlewares for auth checking etc...

Comment: [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: I completely agree with @MagnusEriksson just wanted to add that closures in routes are also not the smartest idea in the world. At one time or another you might want to serialize your routes (caching) and closures are not serializable.